# auto resize height of UIToolbar in landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, rotation, uitoolbar, autoresize

I've got a custom UIToolBar which doesn't adjust it's height to match the navigationbar on the top of the screen when I rotate to landscape mode. The height stays the same which makes it look a bit weird. The default toolbar from the UINavigationController actually reduces in size when rotated to landscape (unfortunately I can't use it because of push/pop transition issues). The current resizing mask is :

```
[ customToolbar setAutoresizingMask: ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin ) ];
```

If I add "UIViewAutoresizingFlexible**Height**" strange things happen...so I'm not quite sure if I should use this.

Please let me know if anyone knows the correct way to auto resize/rotate the UIToolBar to match the navigationbar height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to resize your custom toolbar with the same aspect ratio as standard navigation bar you should implement willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation controller method like this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect navigationToolbarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGRect customToolbarFrame = CGRectOffset(navigationToolbarFrame, 0.0, navigationToolbarFrame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.customToolbar.frame = customToolbarFrame;     
    }];
}
```

Comment: Very nice touch with the animation.

Comment: In regards to voromax answer, when I implemented those lines of code my toolbar ended up in the middle when rotated to landscape mode. How do I shift it to the bottom? Anyone know? (I couldn't comment for some reason under his answer)

Comment: @Masterminder If you want to have toolbar at the bottom why don't you use standard UINavigationController' toolbar? In your case I can make an assumption that you have the navigation bar disabled. Therefore this method cannot resolve the toolbar's frame during rotation

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve that is to create a `UINavigationcontroller` and present it as a modal view, I use something like this:

```
NewViewController *f = [[NewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewView"
                                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.newViewController = f;

[f release];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                           initWithRootViewController:self.newViewController];

 [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Since you're presenting the view as a navigatiocontroller you can use the toolbar property.

Comment: Hmm I think I need to clarify my problem a bit. I have two view controllers, both are part of a navigationcontroller. When I push the second viewcontroller I want there to be a toolbar, not on the first one. When I use the default navigationcontroller ToolBar the transition is really ugly (black square visible). So I've created a custom toolbar which I add to the view of the second view controller. This way it stays 'attached' to the screen during transitions. The only thing left is to make my custom toolbar rotate and resize the height properly in landscape mode. Can it be solved with masks?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about masks, but you can resize the view in -willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:. Simply change the frame there to suit your needs. You can also do it in -willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: